# Constraining movement of a SKSpriteNode to a fixed area within a scene

Tags: sprite-kit

How can I constrain manual movement of an SKSpriteNode to a fixed rectangular area within a scene?  This fixed rectangular area a also a SKSpriteNode which is fixed within the scene.  In other words, I want to constrain manual movement of an object (SKSpriteNode) to be completely contained within another SKSpriteNode or at least in the same space that it occupies.  I have tried several different approaches (e.g. using an SKShapeNode that has an edged-based physics body), but nothing seems to work.  This seems like it should be a fairly simple task to accomplish.  Thanks for any help or hints you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an if statement around your moving code - so don't carry out the movement if it will take the object past your boundary. e.g.

```
//check that a positive movement won't take your node past the right boundary
if(node.position.x + yourXMovementValue < boundaryXRight){
    //move your node
}

//same for y
```

Comment: Yes of course!  Thanks!  However, when I implement this logic, sometimes my object stops (visually) short of the boundary and sometimes if stops just past the boundary.  Is this because the touchesMoved method cannot keep up with movement events?

Comment: No prob, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: This approach doesn't help if you have SpriteKit applying dynamic physics to your nodes, like gravity or force.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let rangeX = SKRange(lowerLimit: CGFloat, upperLimit: CGFloat)
    let contraintX = SKConstraint.positionX(rangeX)
    let rangeY = SKRange(lowerLimit: CGFloat, upperLimit: CGFloat)
    let contraintY = SKConstraint.positionY(rangeY)
    yourObject.constraints = [contraintX, contraintY]
```

Comment: Introduce your solution code with at least one sentence describing what it does.